# How can I crop an image to a circle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, gdi+

I'm trying to crop an image to a circle, where the area outside of the circle is white.

The new image dimensions would be the same as the original, just effectively rounding the image.

I'm familiar with how to crop an image using GDI+ to draw a rectangle/square by taking the existing image and copying it into a new one but i can't see how to fill the outside of an arc/circle with white.

Is this possible?

update - i want to do it server side because different browsers/platforms render css radius differently, or not at all

my work so far is:

```
public static Image CropCircle2(Image imgSource)
    {
        Image imgTarget = new Bitmap(imgSource.Width, imgSource.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgTarget);
        var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        path.AddEllipse(0, 0, imgTarget.Width, imgTarget.Height);
        g.SetClip(path);
        g.DrawImage(imgSource, 0, 0);

        return imgTarget;
    }
```

Comment: You can do it just with html you know ?

Comment: why a close vote? explain please...

Comment: I'm not the one who voted to close, and I wouldn't have in this case. But often "how do I..." questions are too broad or show too little effort on the part of the asker. I personally think your question is okay because you at least provided the framework where the additional code can be placed. Some notes though-asking "is it possible" is pointless, the answer is almost always "yes". And tags do not belong in titles, they simply belong as tags (I'm specifically referring to "using asp.net").

Answer (score 16):

You need to paint the background to the color that you want first:

```
public static Image CropToCircle(Image srcImage, Color backGround)
{
    Image dstImage = new Bitmap(srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height, srcImage.PixelFormat);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(dstImage);
    using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(backGround)) {
        g.FillRectangle(br, 0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
    }
    GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddEllipse(0, 0, dstImage.Width, dstImage.Height);
    g.SetClip(path);
    g.DrawImage(srcImage, 0, 0);

    return dstImage;
}
```

Test code:

```
Image srcImage = Bitmap.FromFile(@"..\..\080.jpg");
Image dstImage = CropToCircle(srcImage, Color.CadetBlue);
dstImage.Save(@"..\..\080cropped.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Input:
[image]

Output:
[image]

If you want the outside of the image to be transparent then you need to set the pixel format to be one with an alpha channel (instead of the srcImage's pixel format) and use a background color that includes an all transparent alpha. When you save it, be sure to use a file format that supports alpha (png, for example).

Comment: The **Output** image is dead.

Comment: If someone wants to do a transparent background: Bitmap Format `Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` is fine for it.

Comment: The circle crop works fine but the edges are not as smooth.. I found this example which produces a smoother edge.http://codehunk.com/round-image-corner-in-c/

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with HTML and CSS3.

HTML

```
<div class="circular"></div>
```

CSS

```
.circular {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border-radius: 150px;
-webkit-border-radius: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 150px;
background: url(http://link-to-your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

So for your project you could add a div with runat="server", give it a CSS-class and an ID and programatically add the background to the one you want.

C#

```
yourDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "background: url(" + yourLink + ") no-repeat);
```

Check this link for more info.
http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/

Comment: @Sam Jones that's what i was talking about, but if you use border-radius:50%; it would be more flexible and work for every width and height.