# How to make picture circled?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I need to make picture in Word document circled. I adding to doc it like that:

```
Shape pic = wordDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(imageFile, ref missing, ref missing, 50, 0, 125, 125);
```

When you right click on image in Word2016, you can select one of presets, like rounded rectangle, dimond or something other. I understand that thats presets that consists of bunch of properties, yet was not able to find in Word2016 how to select only shape form, maybe it would give a hint on how to solve issue.

Tried:

```
 pic.ShapeStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeStyleIndex.msoShapeStylePreset2;
```

But seems it have no effect at all, and even if I find some preset, this solution seems not reliable (sure that on different workstations presets may be different)

Comment: How can I crop an image to a circle?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26760608/3060520

Comment: @user3060520, I hope to do it using Word lib, transforming image file before inserting its a bit overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @m4o_tim, I was able to solve problem, went with 1st suggestion:

> Use a Picture fill - add a shape with an AutoShapeType of msoOval and then set the Fill.UserPicture property to the image file you want to use

So solution is:

```
Shape shp = wordDoc.Shapes.AddShape((int) MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeOval, 80, 40, 125, 125);
shp.Fill.UserPicture(imageFileNamePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this in Word.

1. Use a Picture fill - add a shape with an AutoShapeType of msoOval and then set the Fill.UserPicture property to the image file you want to use.
2. Crop a picture to a shape - add a picture and then change the AutoShapeType to msoShapeOval.